# Update records in table having count>1

Tags: mysql, count, sql-update

I want to flag records in a table when there is more than one record where FieldA and FieldB are the same. The select is easy of course:

```
Select Count(*) from Table group by FieldA,FieldB having Count(*)>1
```

Now I would like to do an update and set FieldA and FieldB to NULL for those records only. I'm thinking it is some kind of 'join' but that is not something I am terribly familiar with. Is there some fairly simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, using a temporary table with 3 fields: a `MIN(id)` field where `id` is a unique or primary key in `Table`, and the `FieldA` and `FieldB`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_fix AS
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, FieldA, FieldB 
FROM Table GROUP BY FieldA, FieldB having Count(*)>1;
```

We can then update the original `Table` to set all duplicate `FieldA, FieldB` to `NULL` except for the one with the lowest id (which we saved in the `tmp_fix` table):

```
UPDATE Table t 
LEFT JOIN tmp_fix f ON t.FieldA = f.FieldA AND t.fieldB = f.FieldB
SET t.FieldA = NULL, t.fieldB = NULL
WHERE t.id <> f.id;
```

You might want to make a copy of the `Table` before trying this!

Comment: Thanks, as I look at this I realize what I want to do is leave the first of the dupe fields alone and for all the rest pass the id of first dupe to the others in a field like 'MatchedRecord'. Is there a way to modify the above to do this? The one above looks lke ti would re-set all and the change is really update all the records after the original dupe with the ID of the original dupe.

Comment: That's right, it did that as you asked for that, but I had a hunch you might want this instead. I updated the answer.